# home made atom destruction unit

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics, home-experiment, atoms, atomic-physics

Today we learnt at school that atoms can be destructed. I believe Physics is a great science to do experiment and I would like to try it at home. Could you tell me what I need to do it? and is it dangerous?

Comment: Are you talking about nuclear fusion or fission, or something else?

Comment: Thank you. But I don't know what they are.. I want to experiment to destroy an atom. Is it possible to do at home? If it is the case, how can I do it?

Comment: If you get a smoke alarm, it contains some atoms which destroy themselves.  You don't even have to do anything!

Comment: But how will I see that it is broken?

Comment: The process twistor59 is talking about is nuclear decay - the americium-241 in the smoke alarm decays (breaks up) into neptunium-237, photons (light) and alpha particles (Helium nucleus). Is this the kind of "destruction" you were asking about?

Comment: I think you should read about fission, fusion, decay - wikipedia could be good for this.

Comment: Even human body contains some amount of radioactive atoms. For instance: http://muller.lbl.gov/teaching/physics10/old%20physics%2010/physics%2010%20notes/HumanRadioactivity.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it rather asks for a manual about how to construct an experiment than a physics concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An atom is composed of a nucleus surrounded by small particle called
electrons.  Electrons are relatively easy to remove (for example to
make electrical current). So people talk of "destroying" (not really
the proper word) an atom when somehow they "destroy" the nucleus.

Destroying atoms is not a game or something to be experiment with for
fun. It is not even the fact that it could be dangerous (it can be
extremely dangerous), it is simply very difficult to control without
very complex equipment.

Some atoms will transform by themselves into other atoms,
spontaneously, as explained by some of the comments. As they do that
they will produce particles that are often (not only) the nuclei of
very small atoms (the smallest is Hydrogene, and next one is
Helium). These are what is called radioactivity, and (worth repeating)
it can be extremely dangerous. Protection against radioactivity can be
very difficult. Fortunately, natural radioactivity from spontaneous tranformation of atoms is usually very weak (not in Fukushima, though).

Actually you do not destroy atoms, but only transform them into other
atoms, either by fusion of two nuclei into a larger one, or by breaking a
large nucleus into smaller ones, which is called fission.

This can produce large amounts of energy, as in atomic bomb and in
nuclear powerplants.

Here you have plenty of words to search the Internet. If you want as
list of know atoms (up to some details) look at [Mendeleev Periodic
Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table).
There are only about 120 different ones (up to differences that are a
bit to delicate to explain here). These are the basic chemicals
existing in nature.

Now you can assemble them into larger things called molecules, that
constitute all material things around you.  Working with molecule is
chemistry.  There are kit to do simple tranformations of molecules
that are not dangerous (it can be dangerous too, if you are careless).

Good luck in school. That is a good place to learn.  And books too.

Comment: IF you are really interested in sciences, remember you will need your brain.  Maybe slowing down on hamburgers can help preserve that asset. And running is good too.